# I wish to add a space before and after "<use_arg_label>". What xsl transformation should I use?

Tags: xml, xslt

This might sound like a stupid question, but I'm quite new to xslt.
So for the following code

> ```
>     <short_desc>Hello<use_arg_label/>World
>     </short_desc>
> ```

If I use

> ```
> <xsl:template match="use_arg_label">                                               
>     <xsl:text> </xsl:text>                    
> </xsl:template>
> ```

It replaces the tag itself with the whitespace.

I wish to get the output as

> ```
> <short_desc>Hello <use_arg_label/> World
> </short_desc>
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: So how does the rest of your XSLT look like? Do you already have the identity transformation template in place?

Comment: Yes, I have it in place
      <xsl:template match="use_arg_label">
        <xsl:call-template name="arg-label"/>
      </xsl:template>
I just need to add space before and after the <use_arg_label>.
If the code is formatted and I use "normalize-space", it also normalizes the gap provided for <use-arg_label>

Comment: Consider to edit your question and show a minimal but complete XSLT stylesheet together with the input you have, the output you want and the one you currently get. Also which version of XSLT do you use?

Comment: Alright, I'm using xslt version 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use XSLT 2 and later you can simply exploit `xsl:next-match` to delegate copying to the identity transformation:

```
  <xsl:template match="use_arg_label">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

The identity transformation is easily set up in XSLT 3 (see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeg)  with a global declaration

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

or spelled out in XSLT 2 as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1 you need to call the identity transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="use_arg_label">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhi